# How to calculate web page download and loading time?

Tags: php, curl, yslow

I want to calculate full download of a web page time via PHP.

Its possible to use CURL but its only calc download time of HTML source so Its not possible to calc all elements like JS , Images , ... on a page !

I want to program something like hyperspin, Is there any method to act like a webbrowser ?
I mean something like YSlow or hyperspin.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (headless WebKit)

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    t = Date.now();
page.open('http://twitter.com/marcelduran', function (status) {
  t = Date.now() - t;
  console.log(t + 'ms');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this (quite accurately) by sending a cURL request, downloading the first byte, calculating the time taken and then multiplying it by the total amount of bytes to download.

As for JS and images, you'd really just have to make a library for that (or maybe there's already one available)